# Is Nabokov's Pale Fire really in iambic pentameter?

Tags: poetry

The poem is described as written in heroic couplets (iambic pentameter lines with end rhyme).  When I read it, it seems to be to be free verse with end rhyme.  I can't consistently identify the iambs (da-DUM, da-DUM, da-DUM) And when read aloud, it sounds like prose mostly with rhyme.

He's fairly consistent in having 10 syllables in each line. But they don't seem to be made up of 5 iambs.

Comment: Only the most mechanical English iambic pentameter is written in strict form: the poet's art lies in the tension between the nominal five 'feet'  and the actual four primary stresses. Northrop Frye has a very fine treatment [here](http://northropfrye-theanatomyofcriticism.blogspot.com/2009/02/fourth-essay-rhetorical-criticism.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excellent question!

Well, let's figure it out.

Here are the first dozen lines of the poem, and let's mark the instances that don't seem to conform to the iambic canon:

> I was the shadow of the waxwing slain
>   **By the** false azure in the windowpane;
>   I was the smudge of ashen fluff - and I
>   Lived on, flew on, **in the** reflected sky.
>   And from the inside, too, I'd duplicate
>   Myself, my lamp, an apple on a plate:
>   Uncurtaining the night, I'd let dark glass
>   Hang all the furniture above the grass,
>   And how delightful when a fall of snow
>   **Covered** my glimpse of lawn and reached up so
>   As to make chair and bed exactly stand
>   Upon that snow, **out in** that crystal land!
>   Retake the falling snow: each drifting flake
>   **Shapeless** and slow, unsteady and opaque,

As you see, in the first fourteen lines, or six heroic couplets, of the poem there are ***five*** deviations, which is in keeping with traditional English poetry patterns.

***All of them*** are inverted iambs (trochees): no spondees, no dactyls, nothing radical: have you tried scanning Shakespeare?

Consider this sonnet, by John Keats, in which there are ***eight*** such deviations:

> O Solitude! if I must with thee dwell,
>   **Let it** not be among the jumbled heap
>   Of murky buildings; climb with me the steep,—
>   **Nature’s** observatory—whence the dell,
>   Its flowery slopes, its river’s crystal swell,
>   May seem a span; **let me** thy vigils keep
>   ’Mongst boughs pavillion’d, where the deer’s swift leap
>   **Startles** the wild bee from the fox-glove bell.
>   But though I’ll gladly trace these scenes with thee,
>   **Yet the** sweet converse of an innocent mind,
>   Whose words are images of thoughts refin’d,
>   **Is my** soul’s pleasure; and it sure must be
>   **Almost** the highest bliss of human-kind,
>   **When to** thy haunts two kindred spirits flee.

Et voila!

Comment: You might enjoy this...http://youtu.be/Ldpj_5JNFoA

Comment: Actually, *"By the false azure"* is a double iamb, as is *"Is my soul's pleasure"* in the Keats poem. (da, da, DUM, DUM).  But that's another really common (and accepted) deviation in iambic pentameter.